# Python Selenium- Join data tables in excel

Tags: python, excel, selenium, join, datatable

I want to know how can I join 2 data tables from 2 different sheets in excel, and write this joint table in a third sheet.

Data table 1:

```
FT 202003/69362
FT 202003/62581
FT 202003/41307
FT 202003/32316
FT 202003/4664
FT 201903/215090
FT 201903/197043
```

Data table 2:

```
FT 202003/62581
FT 202003/41307
FT 202003/32316
```

Data table I prettend to create:

```
FT 202003/69362
FT 202003/4664
FT 201903/215090
FT 201903/197043
```

So I want to create this data table in "Sheet 3", and this data table is made with values that don't exist in both tables. Can you help me?

Comment: Is it a requirement that you use Python Selenium to solve this?